# Show the component at first time to the website in angular

Tags: angular

angular project: show the video only at first time, when the cookie created, then it should be hidden.
Already I tried with `ng-show` `ng-if` ....

```
<div ng-hide="about-video">
```

and at **component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
}
```

there are many sites shows video while entering first time(component initialization) but later hidden them
Want to know how they achieved it

Comment: How are you storing your cookie? are you saving it in local storage?

Comment: Please post more details, you have empty `ngOnInit`, your html doesn't match your description (*tried with `ng-show`, `ng-if`* but there's `ng-hide` in code), you mention some cookie, do you read its value anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of using a cookie is ok, but local storage is a better solution for you problem.
Juste create a boolean in your component, set it to false.
Then in your ngOnInit read the cookie, if notPresent or contain false then set your boolean to true.

```ts
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
    showVideo:boolean = false

    ngOnInit(){
        this.showVideo = window.localStorage.getItem('showIntroVideo') !== 'true';
        if(!this.showVideo){
            window.localStorage.setItem('showIntroVideo', 'true');
        }
    }
}
```

And in your template :

```xml
<ng-container *ngIf="showVideo">
    <!-- your video goes there -->
</ng-container>
```